# Three.js - load JSON model once and add it multiple times

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, webgl

Is it possible to load a JSON model once and add it to the scene multiple times with different scales, positions, etc?

If I add the Object3D() to an array, give a position and scale to the object in the array, add it to the scene, and then repeat this process, the position and scale are overwritten for every object in the array.

I can't think of anything that works, so I'm hoping someone could give me a working example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here's (one of many) of my failed attempts. Should give you a basic idea of what I'm trying to do, if my explanation wasn't sufficient.

```
 function addModels(){

            var models = [];    

            var model = new THREE.Object3D();       
            var modelTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/model.jpg" );
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "models/model.js", function( geometry ) {
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: modelTex }) );
                model.add(mesh);
            } );

            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
                model.scale.set(i,i,i);
                model.position.set(i,i,i);
                models[i] = model;

                scene.add(models[i]);
            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create new meshes from the same geometries and materials:

```
loader.load( "models/model.js", function( geometry ) {
        var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: modelTex });
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
            mesh.position.set(i, i, i);
            mesh.scale.set(i, i, i);
            scene.add(mesh);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to clone a model first and then set position and scale.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
        var newModel = model.clone();
            newModel.position.set(i,i,i);
            newModel.scale.set(i,i,i);

            scene.add(newModel); 
}
```

Updated: Example how you can create json model without load : [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YFkMy/25/) or just simple add loop inside load function.

Comment: Doing this saves the position and scale for each of the models, but they're not appearing in my scene.

Comment: Load is ajax asynchronous load, you need to make sure that model is loaded before cloning, the easiest way is to add loop inside load function.