# Adding the same model to the scene more than once in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

How is it possible to add the same dae model to a scene more than once?

```
//loading collada model
var soldiers = [];
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load('soldier.dae', function(collada) {
    var dae = collada.scene;

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
        var new_soldier = new THREE.Mesh( dae.geometry, dae.material );
        soldiers.push(new_soldier);
        scene.add(new_soldier);
    }
});
```

The error is: `dae.geometry` and `dae.material` is undefined.
I have no Idea how to solve it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The `collada.scene` variable is `instanceof Object3D` so it does not have geometry or material attributes. What you need to do is to replace the for loop with:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    scene.add( dae );
```

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<10; i++) scene.add( dae );` makes no sense. How can I now give different position/rotation values to this objects? I only want to get ten 3D objects, with the same model.

Comment: Well if you also want to change the positions, scales of the model which you load many times you can clone it. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669721/three-js-load-json-model-once-and-add-it-multiple-times

Comment: In that example there is a JSON loader, which is different from collada loader. How do I get `geometry` and `material` objects from the collada model?

Comment: If you want the geometries and materials of the model you can traverse the object to find them.