# Draw Object3D more times with different location/rotation in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Is it possible to draw Object3D more times with different location/rotation?
I don't want to clone the object, because they will be the same, except for the position/rotation values. So the only one thing I need is a reference to obj's geometries and materials. (the Object3D is a collada model (dae.scene) in my code)

```
var obj = new THREE.Object3D();
//...

var objs = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    objs.push( ? );
}

objs[j].position.set(x, y, z);
//...
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But what you *can* do is to create multiple Object3D instances and add the Collada object that you want to display multiple times as child object to each and every of these objects. 
On each of the Object3D objects you can specify position, rotation and scale thereby rendering your Collada object at several places. 
Your Collada object exists in only one instance but is rendered multiple times because of the Object3D objects.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the same model to the scene without cloning it. The materials and geometries of a collada model can be anywhere in the model hierarchy and you can traverse the hierarchy to find them. Cloning will do just that. Three.js does not have the notion of `instance` of a model (yet).

Take a look at [Three.js - load JSON model once and add it multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669721/three-js-load-json-model-once-and-add-it-multiple-times) as per the cloning.